# How to split variable sized string-based column into multiple columns in Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame which is of the form :

```
A      B       C     D
A1     6       7.5   NaN
A1     4       23.8  <D1 0.0 6.5 12 4, D2 1.0 4 3.5 1>
A2     7       11.9  <D1 2.0 7.5 10 2, D3 7.5 4.2 13.5 4> 
A3    11       0.8   <D2 2.0 7.5 10 2, D3 7.5 4.2 13.5 4, D4 2.0 7.5 10 2, D5 7.5 4.2 13.5 4>
```

The column **D** is a raw-string column with multiple categories in each entry. The value of entry is calculated by dividing the last two values for each category. For example, in 2nd row :

```
D1 = 12/4 = 3
D2 = 3.5/1 = 3.5
```

I need to split column **D** based on it's categories and join them to my DataFrame. The problem is the column is dynamic and can have nearly 35-40 categories within a single entry. For now, all I'm doing is a **Brute Force** Approach by iterating all rows, which is very slow for large datasets. Can someone please help me?

***EXPECTED OUTCOME***

```
A      B       C     D1  D2  D3  D4  D5
A1     6       7.5   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
A1     4       23.8  3.0 3.5 NaN NaN NaN
A2     7       11.9  5.0 NaN 3.4 NaN NaN 
A3    11       0.8   NaN 5.0 3.4 5.0 3.4
```

Comment: If you are looking for a function that does this and creates dynamic columns based on your data, i am afraid there isnt a function that you could use. You could try to use df.apply() to apply a function created by you on a column or a row, and df.assign() to add columns

Comment: @Loukik Yeah, I know. I tried df.apply(), but df.apply() seems slow for large datasets with huge number of row entries. The division could be attained by vectorized operations, but to make the split efficiently is the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use:**

```
d = df['D'].str.extractall(r'(D\d+).*?([\d.]+)\s([\d.]+)(?:,|\>)')
d = d.droplevel(1).set_index(0, append=True).astype(float)
d = df.join(d[1].div(d[2]).round(1).unstack()).drop('D', 1)
```

---

**Details:**

Use [`Series.str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) to extract all the capture groups from the column `D` as specified by the `regex` pattern. You can test the `regex` pattern [`here`](https://regex101.com/r/tXlRn8/1).

```
print(d)
          0     1  2 # --> capture groups
  match             
1 0      D1    12  4
  1      D2   3.5  1
2 0      D1    10  2
  1      D3  13.5  4
3 0      D2    10  2
  1      D3  13.5  4
  2      D4    10  2
  3      D5  13.5  4
```

Use [`DataFrame.droplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html) + `set_index` with optional parameter `append=True` to drop the unused level and append a new index to datafarme.

```
print(d)
         1    2
  0            
1 D1  12.0  4.0
  D2   3.5  1.0
2 D1  10.0  2.0
  D3  13.5  4.0
3 D2  10.0  2.0
  D3  13.5  4.0
  D4  10.0  2.0
  D5  13.5  4.0
```

Use [`Series.div`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html) to divide column `1` by `2` and use [`Series.round`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.round.html) to round the values then use [`Series.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) to reshape the dataframe, then using [`DataFrame.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) join the new dataframe with `df`

```
print(d)
    A   B     C   D1   D2   D3   D4   D5
0  A1   6   7.5  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  A1   4  23.8  3.0  3.5  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  A2   7  11.9  5.0  NaN  3.4  NaN  NaN
3  A3  11   0.8  NaN  5.0  3.4  5.0  3.4
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick reply. I'm able to understand everything except the REGEX part. How was the regex able to filter out only the last 2 values? How were the middle nos.eliminated?

Comment: Hi, saran, Here we are using `.*?`  in regex pattern which matches any character zero to more times but as `few times` as possible. i have provided the link to the explanation for [regex](https://regex101.com/r/tXlRn8/1), please check it.

Comment: Thanks Shubham, was able to understand how the REGEX worked as well. But, still is there any more way to optimize this further? I ran this on a dataset containing 3.5 lakh rows, and ``` str.extractall ``` alone takes nearly 30-32 secs. In my previous Brute force approach, I split the data and iterated in parallel, and that is taking 26-27 secs.

Comment: Thanks @Shubham Sharma. Implementing multiprocessing boosted the solutions' performance.